# Перегрузка оператора

Tags: c++

Не могу разобраться с перегрузкой оператора+. Хочу осуществить возможность к объекту класса (fraction) добавлять число:

```
fraction fr(1,5);
int x = num;

fraction result;
result = x + fr;
```

Comment: нужно перегружать с помощью отдельной функции; `fraction operator+ (int left_op, fraction right_op) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Текущий инстанс:

```
fraction& operator+=(int value)
{
    this->... += value;
    return *this;
}
```

Новый инстанс:

```
fraction operator+(int value) const
{
    return fraction(...);
}

friend fraction operator+(int value, fraction const& f)
{
    return fraction( value + f./*someoneDataMember*/);
   /* return ( f + value );*/
}
```

Comment: так у ТС же слева переменная типа **int**…

Comment: @mymedia, обновил.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
class fraction{
   int value_;
public:
   fraction(int v): value_{v}
   { }

   const fraction& operator += (int lhs){
      value_ += lhs;
      return *this;
   }

   fraction operator + (int lhs) const{
      fraction tmp(value_);
      tmp += lhs;
      return tmp;
   }
}
```

Можно немного проще:

```
...
fraction operator + (int lhs) const{
  return fraction (value_ + lhs);
}
...
```

Это если реализация простая, в общем случае предпочтительно реализовывать + через += для устранения лишнего дублирования кода.

Comment: Добавте немного обьяснений